# Boto "get byte range" returns more than expected

Tags: python, amazon-s3, range, boto

This is my first question here as I'm fairly new to this world!  I've spent a few days trying to figure this out for myself, but haven't so far been able to find any useful info.

I'm trying to retrieve a byte range from a file stored in S3, using something like:

```
S3Key.get_contents_to_file(tempfile, headers={'Range': 'bytes=0-100000'}
```

The file that I'm trying to restore from is a video file, specifically an MXF. When I request a byte range, I get back more info in the tempfile than requested. For example, using one file, I request 100,000 bytes and get back 100,451.

One thing to note about MXF files is that they legitimately contain 0x0A (ASCII line feed) and 0x0D (ASCII carriage return).

I had a dig around and it appears that any time a 0D byte is present in the file, the retrieved info adds 0A 0D instead of just 0D, therefore appearing to retrieve more info than required.

As an example, original file contains the Hex string of:

02 03 00 00 00 00 3B 0A 06 0E 2B 34 01 01 01 05

But the file downloaded form S3 has:

02 03 00 00 00 00 3B 0D 0A 06 0E 2B 34 01 01 01 05

I've tried to debug the code and work my way through the Boto logic, but I'm relatively new at this, so get lost very easily.

I created this for testing, which shows the issue

```
from boto.s3.connection import S3Connection
from boto.s3.connection import Location
from boto.s3.key import Key
import boto
import os


## AWS credentials
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'secret key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'access key'

## Bucket name and path to file
bucketName = 'bucket name'
filePath = 'path/to/file.mxf'

#Local temp file to download to
tempFilePath = 'c:/tmp/tempfile'


## Setup the S3 connection and create a Key to access the file specified
## in filePath
conn = S3Connection(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucketName)
S3Key = Key(bucket)
S3Key.key = filePath

def testRangeGet(bytesToRead=100000): # default read of 100K
    tempfile = open(tempFilePath, 'w')
    rangeString = 'bytes=0-' + str(bytesToRead -1)  #create byte range as string
    rangeDict = {'Range': rangeString} # add this to the dictionary
    S3Key.get_contents_to_file(tempfile, headers=rangeDict) # using Boto
    tempfile.close()
    bytesRead = os.path.getsize(tempFilePath)
    print 'Bytes requested = ' + str(bytesToRead)
    print 'Bytes recieved = ' + str(bytesRead)
    print 'Additional bytes = ' + str(bytesRead - bytesToRead)
```

I guess there is something in the Boto code that is looking out for certain ASCII escape characters and modifying them, and I can't find any way to specify to just treat it as a binary file.

Has anyone had a similar problem and can share a way around it?

Thanks

Tim

Comment: Which boto version are you using?  `boto.__version__`

Comment: Using boto version 2.6.0

Comment: Tried something else, just to make sure that it's not directly related to the {'Range' : 'bytes=0-100000'} bits, so downloaded the whole file using get_contents_as_file and:

Bytes requested = 234630656
Bytes recieved = 235363424
Additional bytes = 732768

Comment: I never experienced such problems using the same version of boto to access S3.  But I also never used Windows to do this (but you seem to, assuming from your temp file path).  Maybe it's a Windows issue?

Comment: And I'm using `key.get_contents_as_string()` only to access the data.  Maybe that's working for you as well?

Comment: No, probably no difference because `get_contents_as_string()` internally also uses `get_contents_to_file()` on a `StringIO` :-/

Comment: Yes, using Windows (at work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your output file as a binary file.  Otherwise writing into that file will convert LF to CR/LF automatically.

```
tempfile = open(tempFilePath, 'wb')
```

That of course is only necessary on Windows systems.  Unixes won't convert anything, regardless whether a file has been opened as text or as binary file.

You should take care when uploading as well that you don't get such-like corrupted data into S3 in the first place.

Comment: Thanks Alfe, it's simple and obvious when someone points it out.  Very much appreciated!