# Reading part of a file in S3 using Boto

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-s3, cloud, boto

I am trying to read 700MB file stored in S3. How ever I only require bytes from locations 73 to 1024.

I tried to find a usable solution but failed to. Would be a great help if someone could help me out.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788290/boto-get-byte-range-returns-more-than-expected

Answer (score 12, accepted):

S3 supports [GET requests using the 'Range' HTTP header](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/GettingObjectsUsingAPIs.html) which is what you're after.

To specify a Range request in boto, just add a header dictionary specifying the 'Range' key for the bytes you are interested in. Adapted from [Mitchell Garnaat's response](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/boto-users/ofK9XERJeAc/hwupkxvxI1sJ):

```
import boto
s3 = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = s3.lookup('mybucket')
key = bucket.lookup('mykey')
your_bytes = key.get_contents_as_string(headers={'Range' : 'bytes=73-1024'})
```

Comment: This is likely the best way to get the contents and preserve bandwidth and memory usage.  Will want to be careful with the results of your fetch and as suggested use get_contents_as_string.  +1

Answer (score 4):

```
import boto3

obj = boto3.resource('s3').Object('mybucket', 'mykey')
stream = obj.get(Range='bytes=32-64')['Body']
print(stream.read())
```

boto3 version from https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1236

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look on the python script here

```
import boto3
region = 'us-east-1' # define your region here
bucketname = 'test'  # define bucket
key = 'objkey' # s3 file 
Bytes_range = 'bytes=73-1024'
client = boto3.client('s3',region_name = region)
resp = client.get_object(Bucket=bucketname,Key=key,Range=Bytes_range)
data = resp['Body'].read()
```