# Amazon S3: Fast way to extract parts of large binary file?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3

I want to read parts of a large binary file on s3.
The file has the following format:

```
Header 1: 200  bytes
Data   1: 10000 bytes
Header 2: 200  bytes
Data   2: 10000 bytes
...
Header N: 200  bytes
Data   N: 10000 bytes
```

I want to extract all the headers and save them to file.
N is typically (1e6->1e8).

What would be the fastest way to do this?

So far I have tried boto3:

```
def s3_open(bucket, key):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    obj = s3.Object(bucket, key)
    f = obj.get()['Body']
    return f

 f = s3_open(bucket, key)
 nread = 0
 while nread < N:
    remaining = N - nread
    n = min(1000, remaining)
    buf = f.read(n * 10200)
    # read 200 bytes from each of these n records and write to file 
    nread += n
```

This is slow when I run it on my local PC. The f.read() call is the bottleneck.

Comment: Did you try `multiprocessing` ? It can speed up to 64 times your computation time with parallel processing.

Comment: I have a hard time finding out how my f variable: botocore.response.StreamingBody works, but I was hoping it was threaded. Is it safe to share f between threads?

Comment: What size is the file? Have you tried downloading the file and doing it all locally? This would greatly reduce the overhead of making multiple calls to S3 and would probably be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30075978/reading-part-of-a-file-in-s3-using-boto), you could parallelize reading using multiprocessing/threading/... by reading smaller (but large) chunks of the file in multiple jobs.

```py
def get_ranges(file_size, chunk_size, n_jobs):
    num_entries, remainder = divmod(file_size, chunk_size)
    assert not remainder  # sanity check for file size
    entries_per_process = num_entries // n_jobs
    assert entries_per_process >= 1
    ranges = [
        [
            pid * entries_per_process * chunk_size,
            (pid + 1) * entries_per_process * chunk_size,
        ]
        for pid in range(n_jobs)
    ]
    # fix up the last chunk in case there's an uneven distribution of jobs and chunks:
    ranges[-1][-1] = file_size
    return ranges


chunk_size = 200 + 10000
file_size = chunk_size * 15000  # assuming 15 000 chunks
ranges = get_ranges(file_size, chunk_size, 16)

for start, end in ranges:
    print(f"spawn something to process bytes {start}-{end}")
```

prints out something like

```
spawn something to process bytes 0-9557400
spawn something to process bytes 9557400-19114800
spawn something to process bytes 19114800-28672200
spawn something to process bytes 28672200-38229600
spawn something to process bytes 38229600-47787000
spawn something to process bytes 47787000-57344400
[...]
```

so combining it with the linked answer and multiprocessing, something like:

```py
import boto3
import multiprocessing 

def process_range(range):
    # To be on the safe side, let's not share the boto3 resource between
    # processes here.
    obj = boto3.resource('s3').Object('mybucket', 'mykey')
    stream = obj.get(Range='bytes=%d-%d' % (range[0], range[1]))['Body']
    stream.read()  # read the objects from the stream and do something with them
    return 42  # lucky number!

if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = boto3.resource('s3').Object('mybucket', 'mykey')
    ranges = get_ranges(obj.content_length, chunk_size, 50)
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as p:
         # use imap() if you need order!
         for result in p.imap_unordered(process_range, ranges):
              pass
```

This is naturally all dry-coded and untested, and there may be off-by-one errors with that range calculation, so YMMV, but I hope this helps :)