# How can I download from S3 in large parts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto3

I have a huge S3 file (3.5 TB) that I need to process on an EC2 instance.
Right now the instance has 500 GB of disk space. I would prefer to not increase this.

The file can be processed in parts. Therefore I was thinking about downloading
7 chunks of 500 GB and process each part in sequence.

How can I download large parts of a S3 file (fast)?

Using boto3 I can download a whole file using  `s3.download_file()`.
Is there some way I can get this to only download parts of a file?

I can also read parts of a file:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
obj = s3.Object(bucket, key)
f = obj.get()['Body']
f.read(N)
```

The problem with this approach is that N=500 GB so this does not fit into memory. I could possibly write some code that reads smaller chunks and write to file. However I imagine that code from Amazon would do a better job at getting this optimized than what I code myself?

I have also tried `aws s3 cp`. This is fast, but there does not seem to be any way to download only parts of a file.

Comment: You can download the file in parts ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html ) but I don't know how to do it in boto. You'll have to create,sign & send the request yourself.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/a/30076927/235961

Comment: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1236#issuecomment-323595404

Comment: It looks like the StreamingBody can also be [read in chunks](https://botocore.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/response.html). I'm not sure if that consumes memory for the whole range, or if it reads a bit at a time. Let us know how you go!